# Make call to Action section centered

Tags: css, wordpress

I have been struggling with this `WordPress` Theme: `TOTAL` for days.

I think I found section that works for me, `Call To Action Section`.

I added Background Image and button, but the problem is that it is not taking up the center of my **HOME** page.

The image dimensions are `1280px X 720px`

It appears as if something is hiding bottom half of the image.

I attached images.
Is there anyone that can see what I am doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to center an image on the background of your homepage. Is this correct?

You can add the following code to the CSS for your home page:

```
body {
 background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvJMy.png') no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Here is a website that I find very helpful with CSS, and some documentation on background... 
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background/

Answer (score 0):

@Angelina,

Try adding the full height of the background image.

```
.classForTheBgImage {
   background: url( link to the image );
   height: 800px;
}
```